# Simulate CSS hover state using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, hover

I would like to know if there is a way that jquery or some other technology can listen for event X and then simulate a different event somewhere else.

The situation I have right now is that I have an image with an image map, and if the user hovers over a mapped area of the image map I want a related part of the content to change states ( in this case activate the hover state ).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$("#element").hover(function(){
  //style some element(s) or do stuff.
});
```

Keeping in mind all your content is client-side, otherwise make an AJAX request and assign accordingly.

Comment: Do you mean *all your content must be on the **client** side* ?